# No internet after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 17.04 and after upgrade I have no internet access. My PC with Ubuntu is connected to Asus router, which is connected to LAN cable. Before upgrade I had no problems with internet. Now I get message that I'm offline. In my network manager the status of my wired connection is "connected". I tried plugging off/on the router and PC, but no luck.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RX790 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port F)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
03:0e.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0fcf:1009 Dynastream Innovations, Inc. ANTUSB-m Stick
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0032 SiGma Micro 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: what's the output of `ping 1.1.1.1`?

Comment: It's upgrade to 18.04 now, but the same problem. Output of ping 1.1.1.1 is Connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: Ok. So now we know it's a connection issue and not a faulty DNS setting. What's the output of `lspci` and `lsusb`?

Comment: One more thing...I am using dnsmasq instead od systemd-resolved, but with upgrade I can not start dnsmasq (error: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use). And when I open firefox I can get to google site and some other sites...

Comment: SOLVED: I deleted profile of ethernet connection in Network  Manager and new connection works ok. Thank you:)

Comment: Put your steps in an answer and accept it to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I deleted profile of ethernet connection in Network Manager and new connection works ok.